# Page not save forms data

Tags: javascript, browser

when a user signuping to my website, browser save the datails.
I want to not save. I use autocomplate="off" but not working.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEVAm.jpg

Comment: `autocomplete` maybe?

Comment: There is no such attribute with name `autocomplate`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `autocomplete="off"` in the `<form>` element. If it is a login form though, many browsers will ignore the attribute.

See more details here: [How to Turn Off Form Autocompletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)